# Date string Comparison not working (MS ACCESS 2010)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to get specific record by comparing date string.
Here is the table

```
UpdateTimeA          -     UpdateUserId
----------------------------------------
2015/09/02 14:39:39  -     User1
2015/09/02 16:57:29  -     User2
2015/09/02 16:58:37  -     User3
```

And here is the query

```
SELECT UpdateUserId, UpdateTimeA From SubmitSheets 
WHERE UpdateTimeA =DateValue('9/2/2015 4:58:37 PM')
```

This query returns  0 records
UpdateTimeA is a `DateTime` type field.

Comment: Note that DateValue() removes the time portion of a date. So this can't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Format:

```
SELECT UpdateUserId, UpdateTimeA
From SubmitSheets
WHERE UpdateTimeA = #9/2/2015 4:58:37 PM#
```

Or you can use the serial functions:

```
SELECT UpdateUserId, UpdateTimeA
From SubmitSheets
WHERE UpdateTimeA = DateSerial(2015, 9, 2) + TimeSerial(16, 58, 37)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use something like this:

```
SELECT UpdateUserId, UpdateTimeA
From SubmitSheets
WHERE Format(UpdateTimeA, "m/d/yyyy hh:nn:ss AM/PM") = '9/2/2015 4:58:37 PM'
```